# Firebase value addition in androidstudio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my firebase keyvalue image

[image: This is my firebase keyvalue image]

This is my code:

```
    Query query = myFirebaseRef.orderByChild("age");
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot get1) {

            for(DataSnapshot get2 : get1.getChildren()) {
                User user = get2.getValue(User.class);
               Log.d("FireBaseTraining", "age =" + user.getAge());

            }
```

**In short form:**

- I want to addition all age value
- like this
- 20+18+19+20+70+....=Sum_age

How to revise the code?

Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get all the ages for user by loop, and sum all the ages.

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().child("username").orderByChild("age").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    int sum = 0;
                    for(DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        User user = data.getValue(User.class);
                        sum = sum + user.getAge();
                    }
                }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you answer my question,
but I tried and get error,
because in my code user.getAge()  seems  is String not Int

Comment: Error:(138, 39) error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to Integer

Comment: Error:(147, 28) error: variable sum is already defined in method onDataChange(DataSnapshot)

Comment: Thank you!!!
I found something wrong with my code,I use parseInt remove some not number in user.getAge()!!!